# Element of Every Subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> *Let $B= \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. Prove that if $y$ is an element of every subset of B, then $y=1$.*

I find this question confusing because I can easily construct valid subsets of B that do not contain 1.

For example: {0,2,4}, {4,5}, etc.

Am I misreading this question?

Comment: I am just as confused as you are. Perhaps the author had something different in mind then what they wrote.

Comment: Ah, the statement is vacuously true. Because the premise is false, the implication is true.

Comment: @Caerus has hit the nail on the head. +1 for him.

Comment: I'm calling shenanigans.  Seriously.  This is a majorly unfair question.  Yes, it's legitimate but *majorly* unfair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $y$ is an element of every subset of $B$. Then $y\in\{1\}$ so $y=1$.

Now this seems stupid, because of course we also have $y\in\{0\}$, so we also have $y=0$.

This is fine, because, as you have probably realised, no such $y$ exists, therefore we can prove $y$ has literally any property.

For instance, we can evoke the [*principle of explosion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) to prove that $y=6$.

We know that $y=1$. Therefore $y=1$ or $y=6$. But we also know $y=0$, therefore $y\ne 1$. So to have $y=1$ or $y=6$ we must have $y=6$. So $y=6$.

Thanks to Henning Makholm for his criticisms concerning the PoE.

Comment: Note that the concrete argument you give here doesn't actually appeal to explosion. It's more akin to "if $y=1$ and $y=2$, then $y=1$" in that it is a direct derivation from the assumptions, and simply _ignores_ the fact that the assumptions are contradictory.

Comment: On the other hand, we would need a more explicit invocation of explosion for "if $y$ is an element of every subset of $B$, then $y=6$".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for the comments. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the following uses poe: y $\in$ A={0,2} U {6}. Y $\in$ B={1,3}U {6}. So $y \in A \cap B=\{6\} $. So y. = 6 as 6 is only element.